# Gradle DSL method not found: 'has()'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

After latest update of android studio , using classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-beta1' , I am getting the following error on gradle sync .
**Error:Gradle DSL method not found: 'has()'**

Any ideas

Update its casused by android volley , full error :

Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\APPS-MOBI**\Android\volley\bintray.gradle' line: 64
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

  > Could not find method has() for arguments [release] on project ':volley' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: could you please provide the full gradle files, or at least the part that is causing the error? (there should be a line number in the error message)

Comment: @Lovis , its coming from android volley:  publish = project.has("release")

Comment: @LovisError:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\APPS-MOBI\dial-a-pro\Android\volley\bintray.gradle' line: 64

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Could not find method has() for arguments [release] on project ':volley' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The Volley project has given the following warning for a while now:

> The has() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 3.0. Please use the hasProperty() or ext.has() method instead.

Changing the line in Volley's `bintray.gradle` file from

```
publish = project.has("release")
```

to

```
publish = project.hasProperty("release")
```

Seems to fix the issue

Comment: I am Facing same Problem But Your solution Not Working in My Project

Comment: @AshishShahi do You set `Compile SDK Version` and `Build Tools Version` to the same value? i.e if first is `API 25`, than second should be `25.0.0`

Comment: I'm using compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0' and it did not solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

I found the publish=project.has("release") around line 64 in bintray.gradle.

in android studio click the top of the project tree and Edit|FindInPath

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem then I tried this:
go to your volley module and comment out "publish = project.has("release")" in the "bintray.gradle" file